# Rewrite Rule absolute path issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with `.htaccess` file.
I'm trying to transform URLs like `www.example.com/news/2` to `www.example.com/index.php?news=$1`.

So far I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?news=$1 [NC,L]
```

This leads me to an error because it tries to find all sources like: `www.example.com/news/styles.css` etc.
What's the problem? Hta file is in the root.

Answer (score 0):

You have three levels there when you are expecting two. Remove "/?" from the end. Also don't use /news/style.css for your css. Thats just pointless. Use /css or /css/news or /resources/news etc.